# Android SMS Api not accepting some sysmbols

Tags: android, sms

When I am sending the user email using `SMS API` then user getting `SMS` but the `@symbol` in the email id is converted into `i`. I am not getting what the issue

Response - "Your Username 'sumitkumarx86¡gmail.com' and Your Password: 6394937647"

Comment: Because you need to convert your `string message`(which you are sending via `SMS API`) to `UTF-8 encoded`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `SMS API` can not send plain text directly its uses `UTF-8` format to `encode plain text`.

Try this to encode to `UTF-8`:

```
try {
        String message = URLEncoder.encode("jkghfjkdh@gjk.comm", "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the other hand if you want to `decode` it to `plain text`:

```
try {
    String strPlainText = URLDecoder.decode(message, "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```